# Множественное число, родительный падеж слова "узда"

Tags: множественное-число

Как надо сказать "у меня нет узды", если их много?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *У меня нет узд*. Форма родительного множественного числа несвободна, т.е. её трудно произнести. Но она существует, что действительно можно установить по любому подходящему словарю (толковому, орфоэпическому, грамматическому).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x

Посмотрите еще, что во множественном числе ударение всегда падает на первый слог: **у**зды, **у**здам.

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаетесь -- открывайте словарь.

Вот [парадигма слова "узда"](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=355638). (Я пользуюсь [словарём Opencorpora](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php), можете смотреть в любом другом словаре. Вот, например, то же слово [в викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0))

Вам нужен родительный падеж (нет кого/чего) множественного числа. Смотрим ответ - "узд".

Comment: *Таких каверзных вопросов на множественное число много можно вспомнить. Как например, известное* - И что? Мы пятый год тут только тем и занимаемся, что отвечаем на каверзнвые вопросы.  Не надо столько менторства в ответ вкладывать, нравоучения не по сути обычно отталкивают новичков. Говорю Вам как человеку опытному в SE, не знаю уж, на каком ресурсе Вы обитаете,  но понять должны, здесь своя специфика. На такие вопросы (как и на почти все остальные) принято отвечать конкретно и без эмоций. Или вовсе не отвечать и закрывать.

Comment: @behemothus спасибо за наставление, учту.